# noob in java: java syntax

Tags: java, syntax-error

```
if (valid(num1,base)) && (valid(num2,base)){
      while(num1>0 || num2>0){
        String d1 = extractDigit(num1);
        String d2 = extractDigit(num2);
        num1 = removeDigit(num1);
        num2 = removeDigit(num2);
        String d3 = d1 + d2;
        if (d3 >= Integer.parseInt(base)){
          carry = d3/Integer.parseInt(base);
          d3 = d3 % Integer.parseInt(base);
        }
        else{
          carry = 0;
        }
        ans = makeAns(ans, idx, d3);
        idx = idx + 1;
      }
      if (carry > 0){
        ans = makeAns(ans,idx,carry);
      }
      return ans;
    }else{
      return "Invalid input";
    }
```

the first line using the && operator is giving me an error that say 'Illegal start of expression'

Comment: You have two closing parens, when you need only one, following that method call, before the `&&`. It should be `if (valid(num1,base) && valid(num2,base))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have too many parentheses in that line.

```
if (valid(num1,base)) && (valid(num2,base)){
```

should be

```
if (valid(num1,base) && valid(num2,base)){
```

The entire if statement requires parens around the conditional, like you've done in your other if & while statements